# Siri Intents without donation not visible in the settings

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I've created a Siri Intent as described in the following tutorial: [link to the tutorial](https://bendodson.com/weblog/2018/06/05/custom-intents-with-sirikit-ios-12/)

I've added a single intent with a single paramter. I haven't donated the intent. I can't see the intent in "Siri Shortcuts" page in Settings.

**Should the intent be donated, before becoming visible in Siri Settings?**

In my app the balance is always shown in the  homepage, so should I donate the shortcut each time the user views the homepage? Is it possible to specify the shortcut as "available", so it would be automatically added to the settings upon app installation?

[image: Settings page]

Comment: Yes, to let Siri knows your action, you must donate it to Siri at least once (or turn on isEligibleForPrediction in case you use NSUserActivity)

Comment: Does `NSUserActivity` always result in app launch?

Comment: No, NSUserActivities could be done every time they invoked

Comment: Got it. I think, `NSUserActivity` is a better fit here.

Answer (score 1):

You can suggest shortcuts, although the user did not execute the specific action in the app, which would have caused a donation. 
For this, you have to create Suggestions, which might be interesting for the user, and give them to the **INVoiceShorcutCenter**.

The following code might help you:

```
var suggestions : [INShortcut] = []

let intent = CustomIntent()
intent.name = "Suggested Shortcut"

if let image = UIImage(named: "intenticon"), let data = image.pngData() {
   intent.setImage(INImage(imageData: data), forParameterNamed:\CustomIntent.name)
}

intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Show the name"
if let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: intent) {
   suggestions.append(shortcut)
}       

// Suggest the shortcuts
INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions(suggestions)
```

To delete all suggestions, you just suggest an empty **INShortcut** array.

Comment: Thanks for another suggestion. But I decided to go with "view" intent and donate it every time the user views something.